# PHP function to determine is all elements in an array are null

Tags: php, arrays, isnull

I want to know if there is a built-in, or better method to test if all elements of an array are null.

Here is my (working) solution:

```
<?php
    function cr_isnull($data_array){    
        foreach($data_array as $value){ 
            if(!is_null($value)){return false;}
        }
    return true;
    }
?>
```

Explanation:

- If the function finds ANY value in the array that is not null it
  returns false, otherwise after "looping" through all of the array
  elements it returns true.

I cant use empty() because my definition of empty does not fit PHP's definition.

Any thoughts, or am I good to go with what I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
count(array_filter($myarray,'is_null')) == count($myarray);
```

OR

```
array_reduce($myarray,
             function($result,$value) {
                 return $result && is_null($value);
             },
             TRUE
);
```

Comment: Probably don't need the second `count()`, OP just wants to see if all values are `null` or not.

Comment: @nickb - so how would it test that the filter was returning all the original values or not without the count? Using an array_reduce() could eliminate the need for a count() though

Comment: If it's an array of all null values, `array_filter()` will return an array with zero elements. Compare it to `0`, if it's true, the original array had all nulls, if not, it didn't.

Comment: @nickb - If the callback function returns true (is_null will return TRUE if a value is NULL), the current value from input is returned into the result array.... meaning that the returned array will have __all__ its original elements if they were all NULL values. Alternatively, you could create a callback that would use !is_null() to return an empty array if all the array entries were NULL values

Comment: A slight variation of this worked great for my application. Thanks.